# Turn off brush overlay in Texture Paint mode?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm looking for a way to draw strokes with Texture Paint with soft brush and Strength set to low so that all painted strokes to be the same strength. The problem is that if the mouse button / tablet pen was released (while the stroke wasn't finished), it's better to erase the whole streak, because the strokes will overlay.

[image: overlapping strokes]

Currently if *Strength* is set to something other than 0 the strokes will be painted as it's shown on the left. I'm looking for a way to paint with *Stregth* set to low and get result like on the right (the result on the right was created with *Strength* set to 1).
It seems that in the [wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/en/sculpt_paint/painting/texture_paint/options.html#common) is written about blend modes, but either no denial nor approval on whether this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this will help, but i think its the answer your looking for..

In Texture Paint, on the tools tab on the Left (shown in your picture)
underneath radius and strength, is a blend option.. you have it set to "Mix" you can change this to lighten, Darken, Multiply, Subtract, etc..

try messing around with these options and see if that helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. As I get it, the way to achieve what I was going back then is to set *Strength* to 1 and adjust color of the brush. The reason is that all the blend modes will perform some operation on the strokes, while I was trying to find how to make them not affecting intensity of the stroke.